# how to find last element where element is NOT NULL from json array

Tags: jquery, json

How to check or display the last call_no where call_no IS NOT NULL using below JSON. Please help.

> [ 
>      {
>       "client_name":null,
>       "call_no":"null" 
>     },
>     {
>       "client_name":null,
>       "call_no":"null"  },  {
>       "client_name":"Acheiva Technologies",
>       "call_no":1  },  {
>       "client_name":"Allied International",
>       "call_no":2  },  {     "client_name":"Advantage",    "call_no":3  },  {    "client_name":null,    "call_no":"null"  } ]

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** for that

```js
var data = [{
  "client_name": null,
  "call_no": "null"
}, {
  "client_name": null,
  "call_no": "null"
}, {
  "client_name": "Acheiva Technologies",
  "call_no": 1
}, {
  "client_name": "Allied International",
  "call_no": 2
}, {
  "client_name": "Advantage",
  "call_no": 3
}, {
  "client_name": null,
  "call_no": "null"
}];

// filtering elements 
var res = data.filter(function(v) {
   // checking `call_no` value
   return v["call_no"] !== "null";
});

// getting last object from filtered arrary
var result = res[res.length - 1];

// getting values from last object
document.write(result["call_no"],'<br>',result["client_name"]);
```

Comment: @AjayKrishnaDutta : glad to help

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{
  "client_name": null,
  "call_no": "null"
}, {
  "client_name": null,
  "call_no": "null"
}, {
  "client_name": "Acheiva Technologies",
  "call_no": 1
}, {
  "client_name": "Allied International",
  "call_no": 2
}, {
  "client_name": "Advantage",
  "call_no": 3
}, {
  "client_name": null,
  "call_no": "null"
}];

callNo = data[0].call_no;

for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  if(data[i].call_no != "null"){
    callNo = data[i].call_no;
  } 
}
alert(callNo)
```